# Devise: Edit registration form not showing values when used in non Devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, form-for

I've added the resource helper methods to my settings controller so that I can update the `current_user` from within the controller. I've taken the `form_for` from registrations/edit and copied it into my settings controller view. I'm able to successfully update the user, but the existing values aren't showing up in the form as they would if I open users/registrations/edit. It's the same code displaying each form. What am I missing?

settings_controller.rb

```
helper_method :resource_name, :resource, :devise_mapping, :resource_class

def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end

def resource_class
  User
end
```

devise/registrations/edit.html.erb and general.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
  <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Has it been resolved yet?